# Scroll Position in a Table Body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to implement infinite scrolling (with an AJAX-based loader) in an HTML table body.

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I get a scroll bar on the `<tbody>` like so:

```
tbody {
  height:10em; /* Otherwise the tbody expands to fit all rows */
  overflow:auto;
}
```

To be able to do anything when the user scrolls to the bottom, I need to be able to get the scroll position of the `<tbody>`. In all of the (jQuery) infinite scroll implementations I've seen ([such as this one](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/)), they subtract the content height from the container height and compare it to the .scrollTop() value.

Unfortunately this may not work with `<tbody>`, which is both the viewport *and* the container for the scrolled content. `$("tbody").height()` returns the viewable (ie: "shrunken") size, but I don't know how I can get the full (viewable + hidden) size of the table body. (FWIW, `$("tbody").scrollTop()` returns a "large" number when scrolled to the bottom, exactly as I would expect it to).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: *crickets*. The views keep going up but there's no activity. I'm guessing that this is simply not possible given current browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tbody.scrollHeight` works for me.

Comment: That's excellent, except that it's JavaScript (and not jQuery) and thus prone to (IE) browser bugs/inconsistencey (see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36). However, it's probably good enough for a tbody solution.

Answer (score 2):

When you need the hidden height you can set the height to auto, grab it, then return the height to the forced size.

```
var $tbody = $('tbody');
var initTbodyHeight = $tbody.height();
$tbody.css('height','auto');
var autoTbodyHeight = $tbody.height();
$tbody.css('height',initTbodyHeight);
```

Even IE should process this fast enough without any flicker visible to human eyes.